# How to create a 3D effect in Inkscape as required by the Android Design Guidelines?

Tags: icon, inkscape, 3d, svg, android

In the [Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) section if the Android Design Guide they describe the following style that should be used for Launcher Icons:

> [image: Examples of the 3D effect]
>
> Use a distinct silhouette. Three-dimensional, front view, with a slight perspective as if viewed from above, so that users perceive some depth.

I'd like to know how to create this effect with Inkscape. At the moment I just have a two-dimensional shape and don't know how to continue.

Comment: what an odd aesthetic decision by Android. They all feel like they're tipping forward.

Comment: @DA01 if you think about the angle you normally hold a phone at, it's usually tilted away from you, not straight up

Answer (score 7):

The effect you described is simply achieved by duplicating the shape, changing it to outline, moving it up a bit and putting it in the background.

What the website you linked to describes is a concept of creating a depth perception. The examples you have given are not meant to represent the final design but how this effect is basically executed. The final design should be detailed and represent the function of the app. This is a lot more work than the effect you asked for.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that I have to do more than just this but all the other stuff is not my problem at the moment. I hoped for some more detailed instructions. So if you'd explain step by step how you created the icon, I'd be happy.

Comment: you want exactly this design? it's just an example

Comment: No, I just want instructions how to create this 3D effect starting from the flat logo in Inkscape.

Comment: You could start how I described it. But I would strongly sugest going to Photoshop for texturing.

Comment: KMSTR's description is fairly straight forward. Which part are you having trouble with, Julian?

Comment: If as a reader, you are unsure about how to execute the steps above, there is more detail added to this answer (pertaining to Photoshop however) here http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26420/how-to-go-about-making-a-3d-icon-for-android-app-icon/26422?noredirect=1#comment34269_26422

Answer (score 0):

You can use Extrude Extension... And you can follow my tutorial (site is in Indonesian)...

[3D teks effect in inkscape](http://www.desainew.com/2014/08/tutorial-efek-teks-3d-di-inkscape.html)

[image: 3D effect in inkscape]

More at [www.desainew.com](http://www.desainew.com/)

Comment: It would be best if you posted your tutorial here (at least an abridged version).